# filterBounds() error in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, elevation

I wanted to clip the ALOS elevation model to an ROI. This is the code I wrote.

```
var dem = ee.Image("JAXA/ALOS/AW3D30_V1_1");
var geometry = 
    /* color: #ffc82d */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[1.3787373046875473, 49.38636777007675],
          [1.3787373046875473, 48.32016208111379],
          [3.5265644531250473, 48.32016208111379],
          [3.5265644531250473, 49.38636777007675]]], null, false);

var clipdem = dem.filterBounds(geometry)
```

But it gave me this error:

> dem.filterBounds is not a function

I tried casting it to an imageCollection before applying the function, but it doesn't clip the image - giving me the image for the entire world. What is causing it and is there a way to work around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering is for imageCollections. To clip an image, try this instead:

```
var dem = ee.Image("JAXA/ALOS/AW3D30_V1_1");

var geometry =
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[1.3787373046875473, 49.38636777007675],
          [1.3787373046875473, 48.32016208111379],
          [3.5265644531250473, 48.32016208111379],
          [3.5265644531250473, 49.38636777007675]]], null, false);

var clipdem = dem.clip(geometry);
Map.addLayer(clipdem, {min:0,max:250}, "DEM");
Map.centerObject(clipdem, 9);
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked.

Comment: But is there a way to get the raster that is restricted to the geometry? clipping gives me a raster that has a 0 value outside the geometry. Can I get something that does the same thing that filterBounds does

Comment: Sounds like a different issue. Maybe something mask-related? Probably worth asking another question for that one.